# Is it possible to not trigger :hover on ::before or ::after?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, tooltip

I'm trying to make a custom tooltip implementation in CSS, which is working pretty decently, but I'm running into a problem. Currently, hovering over the tooltip still keeps the tooltip opened, even though I'm not hovering over the original element itself.

Of course I've tried something like `::before:hover {display:none;}`, but that doesn't work because pseudo-elements don't get pseudo-classes applied to them.

My next thought was to simply make the tooltip not "take up" any space. Using negative `margin-bottom` allows other stuff to take up space in an element as if the element is not there. However, the `:hover` pseudo-class apparently still applies then.

Here's a demo of what I'd like to do. I'd like to have the tooltip of the following demo not persist any hovering state. Note that moving the tooltip-text higher above the element is not a working solution, because moving the cursor upwards faster than a snail's pace will cause some pixels to be skipped, which means the tooltip 'catches' the cursor and persists the `:hover` on the element.

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Spacer text</p>
<div data-tooltip="Example tooltip">Hover over me for a tooltip text</div>
```

As you can see, if you move your cursor over the div, the tooltip will appear, and if you *slowly* move your cursor up, the tooltip will disappear. If you move your cursor upwards slightly faster, however, it'll skip the 1-pixel gap, and keep the cursor hovering over the div.

Now I'm looking for some styles to apply to `[data-tooltip]::before` so that the cursor's hover events are not triggered on it (or at least, not at the location you see the tooltip; if I can hide it somewhere at [-1000, -1000] that's fine as well)

---

So basically, my question is, is it possible to apply css to an element so that `:hover` does not apply to (part of) an element? I'd love to hear ideas or suggestions.

Comment: If I can somehow get (part of) an element not to trigger `:hover`, then I can apply those styles to `::before` and that'll solve my problem. Also, as I mentioned in the question, I specifically want to solve it without having to overlay some other element on top of the div. In the tooltip example, I can't have other elements layered over my tooltip, otherwise it'll not be visible.

Comment: @MrLister for clarity's sake I've removed the first example, because it was probably just distracting from the actual question.

Comment: OK, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around the internet for a while I finally found a solution that works flawlessly. I didn't really know about this before, but apparently there's a `pointer-events` style that does exactly what I want. Its accepted values outside of SVG are `auto` and `none`, but luckily the latter prevents all hover-events from triggering on the `::before` pseudo-element.

Here's a demo:

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
  /*** this style prevents persistence of the tooltip when hovering over it ***/
  pointer-events: none;
  /* the rest is just the styles used in the question */
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* changed from -2px to 0 so the effect is more clearly shown */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Spacer text</p>
<div data-tooltip="Example tooltip">Hover over me for a tooltip text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but regarding the first question (red div, blue on hover), you could shorten the divs `height` and use `border-bottom` for making up for the lost height:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px; /* instead of 100px */
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red; /* adds 50px to divs apparent height, but ignored at hover */
}
```

Comment: ok, apparently the first part of the question got edited in the meantime. but perhaps the approach can still be applied, i.e. using `border` to make the div take up the desired space whilst avoiding triggering `:hover` in that space.

Comment: Not reallly what I'm looking for in the end, but this is a nice one to look into for possibilities, thanks!